# How to subscribe to external API from docker container, without knowing host ip?

Tags: docker, environment-variables, publish-subscribe

I want to subscribe to an external publish/subscribe API from within a docker container. For subscribing I need to give the IP address, port and endpoint on which my service can receive data when an event happens.

The problem is that from inside of the container I don't know the IP address  of the docker host, to which the external API has to send the data.

I think the problem can be solved by passing the host IP as an environment variable to the container, but because the service has to be installed on many different hosts I don't want to manually setup environment variables for each host.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Note that you have to do the same thing in many many environments, and I’d just pass it in as an environment variable.  (“My laptop’s IP address is 192.168.1.2 at home but that’s not a routable IP address.”  “My service is behind a load balancer.”  “All inbound traffic needs to go through the corporate firewall, which will then reroute it.”)

Comment: Maybe an option is to write a shell script that puts the ip address in environment variables and sets up the docker compose stuff. That way there would be no manual setup, except for running the script.

Comment: Also consider a [Docker Compose env_file:](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#env_file) block to provide the environment variables alongside the Compose specification.

Comment: Thanks for you input @DavidMaze. So I could write a script that puts the ip address of the host in a docker env_file. Then I could use this env variable for registering to the API for each of the hosts.

Answer (score 0):

I finally ended up running the service on the host network by adding

```
network_mode: host
```

to my service in docker-compose.yml

This way the docker container gets an ip address in the hosts network, so it just register to the external API using it's own ip address.

Note that this solution does not work on OS X or Windows, since docker runs on a virtual server on these operating systems.

I retrieve the IP address for my service as follows in java.

```
public static InetAddress getCurrentIp() {
    try {
        Enumeration<NetworkInterface> networkInterfaces = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
        while (networkInterfaces.hasMoreElements()) {
            NetworkInterface ni = networkInterfaces.nextElement();
            Enumeration<InetAddress> nias = ni.getInetAddresses();
            while(nias.hasMoreElements()) {
                InetAddress ia= nias.nextElement();
                if (!ia.isLinkLocalAddress() 
                        && !ia.isLoopbackAddress()
                        && ia instanceof Inet4Address) {
                    return ia;
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (SocketException e) {
        LOG.error("unable to get current IP " + e.getMessage(), e);
    }
    return null;
}
```